# What are all the mistakes in this Specsavers ad?

Tags: commercial

In this [recent ad for Specsavers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRFcAFZmcMI) that was shown on Australian TV, at the start they say there is 15 mistakes in it. so far all I can see are:

- The Hammer seems to be working in reverse (the nail is coming out)
- the brush shows it's been put in Pink Paint but it's paining blue
- at the end the dog eating from the bowl is not the same breed

I am wondering what are all the mistakes are?

Comment: *"...at the start they say there **is** 15 mistakes in it..."* Tell me that was intentional. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The video says there are over 15 but I found following mistakes.

1. The hammer works reverse. The nail is coming out instead of going inside.
2. He paints blue on the wood however the paint on the brush is pink and the castle is pink in the end.
3. Moustache appears at 00:07 and disappears later.
4. The words in the newspaper the woman is reading are a mirror image.
5. There was a plant in the tray in front of the woman at 00:09 but it disappears later.
6. When the man says that the castle has changed to a princess dream castle, there are glasses on his head but when he comes out, there are no glasses.
7. Two girls, when they are inside, are not same as when they come out. When they come out, they are twins.
8. In the next moment, the girl with the brown hair has returned.
9. The blonde girl is wearing a T Shirt over the pink dress and a silver crown.
10. Girl with black hair gets wings and a cream coloured jacket.
11. It was bulldog when it is in kennel. When it comes out and eats from the bowl, it is a different breed.
12. When the different breed dog is out, both the girls attire has returned.
13. Man's shirt changes colours throughout the ad. In the beginning, it was a blue shirt and a blue T shirt with "kill" written on it which changes to a blue shirt with a magenta T shirt with "kill" written whereas in the end, it is a green shirt and a [magenta-ish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magenta) T shirt with "INDI RUGBY CLUB" written on it.
14. Woman's hairstyle changes thrice during the ad.
15. The clothesline changes color.
16. There is no rug on the floor when the man first walks into his house but when the camera changes back to the girls there is a rug.
17. Near the end, there is a lawn mower next to the dog kennel and the camera cuts to the children before cutting back to the dog house, where there is no longer a lawn mower.

Comment: I'm not in a place where I can watch a video, but... Does it say over 15, or exactly fifteen? If there are only 14 mistakes, but it says 15 mistakes, then the 15th mistake is saying 15 when there are only 14, which means there *are* 15, which means... You see where this is going?

Comment: @T.J.L. It says there are over 15. I also think that saying 15 mistakes is also a mistake. I watched the ad many times and didn't spot more than these. I mixed two mistakes about girls in a single point. I think I already spotted 15 mistakes.

Comment: the dog's name is not Cubby. The kids have a "cubby house" (https://www.bing.com/search?q=cubby+house&form=EDGNTT&qs=PF&cvid=cc24b72faa8541d4b3086eac4abe86c6&refig=6cde654178de44c6c78f96105e5b255b&cc=CA&setlang=en-US) and the father intended to change it into a princess castle but accidentally did the doghouse instead - because he doesn't have good glasses, I guess.

Comment: I would say the man's shirt changing multiple times would also be multiple mistakes, taking it over 15.

Comment: 7 & 8 should count as one mistake, as should 10 & 12

Answer (score -2):

The paint bucket to the left of the kennel is in visible sight but then the camera goes to the side and you can’t see it.

Comment: Welcome to movies.se!  While this answer has part of the answer, we prefer answers to be canonical.  IE, an answer should be able to stand by itself and provide a complete answer to the question.